# Nest JSON Data from array

Tags: json, api, format

I am trying to nest JSON data from an array so it is like:

```
{
"subscriptionState" : "SUBSCRIBED",
"division" : {
    "value" : "Retail"
}
,
"attributes" : {
    "attributes" : [
        {
            "name" : "email",
            "value" : "john@doe.com"
        }
    ,
        {
            "name" : "firstName",
            "value" : "John"
        }
    ,
        {
            "name" : "lastName",
            "value" : "Doe"
        }
    ,
        {
            "name" : "postalCode",
            "value" : "97209"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Currently my data looks like:

```
{
"subscriptionState": "UNSUBSCRIBED",
"division": {
    "value": "UK"
},
"attributes": {
    "email": "karina@test.com",
    "firstName": "Karina",
    "lastName": "McG",
    "postCode": "BT93 EP3",
    "prefersMobile": "",
    "emailFormat": "HTML"
  }
}
```

Code:

```
$ym_api_url = 'https://connect.api.com/import';
$newsubscriber = array(
'subscriptionState' => 'UNSUBSCRIBED',
'division' => array(
'value' => 'UK'
),
'attributes' => array(
'firstName' => 'Karina',
'lastName' => 'McGourty',
'postCode' => 'BT93 EP3',
'prefersMobile' => '',
'emailFormat' => 'HTML'
)
);
```

What would be the correct way to do this, so far i have tried something like:

```
'attributes' => array(
'attributes' => array(
(
'name' => 'email',
'value' => 'karina@test.com'
),
(
'name' => 'firstName',
'value' => 'Karina'
)
```

but no joy?

Comment: Can you please try this JSON.stringify(yourArray);

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out myself in the end, i know its a simple question but thought i would share my answer in case anybody comes across this:

```
$newsubscriber = array(
'subscriptionState' => 'UNSUBSCRIBED',
'division' => array(
'value' => 'UK'
),
'attributes' => array(
'attributes' => array(
array(
'name' => 'email',
'value' => 'Karina@email.com'),
array(
'name' => 'firstName',
'value' => 'Karina'),
array(
'name' => 'lastName',
'value' => 'McG'),
array(
'name' => 'postalCode',
'value' => 'BT93 EP3'),
array(
'name' => 'prefersMobile',
'value' => '-1'),
array(
'name' => 'emailFormat',
'value' => 'HTML')
     )
   )
);
```